# Python fill 30 data into 31 row

Tags: python-3.x

got array

```
[ [26, 'Yes'], [27, 'Yes'], [28, 'Yes'], [29, 'Yes'], [30, 'Yes'], 
  [1,  'Yes'], [2,  'Yes'], [3,  'Yes'], [4,  'Yes'], [5,  'Yes'], 
  [6,  'Yes'], [7,  'Yes'], [8,  'Yes'], [9,  'Yes'], [10, 'Yes'], 
  [11, 'Yes'], [12, 'Yes'], [13, 'Yes'], [14, 'Yes'], [15, 'Yes'], 
  [16, 'Yes'], [17, 'Yes'], [18, 'Yes'], [19, 'Yes'], [20, 'Yes'], 
  [21, 'Yes'], [22, 'Yes'], [23, 'Yes'], [24, 'Yes'], [25, 'Yes'] ]
```

And row with number `26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16.....25`
how can I fill the row 31 with string "None"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding your question, you can find the index of the 30 sublist element, add 1 to the index, and insert the [31,None] at that index.

```
arr = [[26, 'Yes'], [27, 'Yes'], [28, 'Yes'], [29, 'Yes'], [30, 'Yes'], 
       [1, 'Yes'], [2, 'Yes'], [3, 'Yes'], [4, 'Yes'], [5, 'Yes'], 
       [6, 'Yes'], [7, 'Yes'], [8, 'Yes'], [9, 'Yes'], [10, 'Yes'], 
       [11, 'Yes'], [12, 'Yes'], [13, 'Yes'], [14, 'Yes'], [15, 'Yes'], 
       [16, 'Yes'], [17, 'Yes'], [18, 'Yes'], [19, 'Yes'], [20, 'Yes'], 
       [21, 'Yes'], [22, 'Yes'], [23, 'Yes'], [24, 'Yes'], [25, 'Yes']]

num = 31
nums = [i[0] for i in arr]
arr.insert(nums.index(num-1) + 1,[num,"None"])
```

output:

```
[[26, 'Yes'], [27, 'Yes'], [28, 'Yes'], [29, 'Yes'], [30, 'Yes'],
 [31, "None"], [1, 'Yes'], [2, 'Yes'], [3, 'Yes'], [4, 'Yes'],
 [5, 'Yes'], [6, 'Yes'], [7, 'Yes'], [8, 'Yes'], [9, 'Yes'],
 [10, 'Yes'], [11, 'Yes'], [12, 'Yes'], [13, 'Yes'], [14, 'Yes'],
 [15, 'Yes'], [16, 'Yes'], [17, 'Yes'], [18, 'Yes'], [19, 'Yes'],
 [20, 'Yes'], [21, 'Yes'], [22, 'Yes'], [23, 'Yes'], [24, 'Yes'],
 [25, 'Yes']]
```

Comment: Almost right,but i need the row number 31 fill by "None", not the array @alexpdev